# PHP OOP Simple Calculator Making

Tags: php, html, css, oop

I am a beginner in **PHP** Object Oriented Programming. I want to make a simple calculator where i can input two number and calculate it according to my `function`.I can make just two number input in **OOP** as parameter.But how can i input two number in `<form>` and make connection between `<form>` and `variable` and show the output? As i beginner so please forgive my mistake.
Thanks in advanced.

I have tried so far is :

**index.php :**

```
<?php 
  require 'functions.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <title>PHP OOP | Calculator</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="form_area">
         <form action="" method="POST">
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Number :</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="numOne" placeholder="Input Your First Number"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Second Number :</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="numTwo" placeholder="Input Your Second Number"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="output_area">
        <?php
            if(null !==($_POST['numOne'] && $_POST['numTwo'])){
                $resultsOne = new NumberCalculation();
                echo "Added Results = ".$resultsOne->add()."<br>";
            }
        ?>
      </div>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**functions.php :**

```
<?php

class NumberCalculation{
public $numOne;
public $numTwo;

public function __construct($firstNum, $secNum){
    $this->numOne = $firstNum;
    $this->numTwo = $secNum;
}
public function add(){
    return $this->numOne + $this->numTwo;
}
public function subtruct(){
    return $this->numOne - $this->numTwo;   
}
public function multiple(){
    return $this->numOne * $this->numTwo;   
}
public function divide(){
    return $this->numOne / $this->numTwo;   
}
}
global $numOne, $numTwo;

$resultsOne = new NumberCalculation($numOne,$numTwo);
?>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: My problem is that i can input two number but i can i show the output ?

Comment: you should pass a "numOne" or "numTwo" on "NumberCalculation" class for displaying output like you did at the bottom of the functions.php file

Comment: You forget to pass two number in your constructor

Comment: I do not want pass parameter in `NumberCalculation` .I want to give two input and calculate button will calculate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you almost had it.  Put your inputs from your `$_POST` variable to your  `NumberCalculation` class constructor

```
$resultsOne = new NumberCalculation($_POST['numOne'],$_POST['numTwo']);
echo "Added Results = ".$resultsOne->add()."<br>";
```

---

if you don't want to pass something to your `NumberCalculation` class constructor.  you can do the ff:

```
$resultsOne = new NumberCalculation();
$resultsOne->numOne = $_POST['numOne'];
$resultsOne->numTwo = $_POST['numTwo'];
echo "Added Results = ".$resultsOne->add()."<br>";
```

Comment: I am looking for this.Can you tell me difference between `isset` and `null !==` ?

Comment: `isset` checks if a `variable` is already set,  while `null !==` is just a simple comparation.

Answer (score 1):

You were not passing the form posted values. Do like this..

```
<?php
    if(null !==($_POST['numOne'] && $_POST['numTwo'])){
        // pass your values like below
        $resultsOne = new NumberCalculation($_POST['numOne'], $_POST['numTwo']); 
        echo "Added Results = ".$resultsOne->add()."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add third param(`$funcName`) to function for global use. You just need to pass action name such as add, multiple, divide etc.

**functions.php :**

```
class NumberCalculation{
            public $numOne;
            public $numTwo;
            private $result;

                public function __construct($firstNum, $secNum, $funcName){
                    $this->numOne = $firstNum;
                    $this->numTwo = $secNum;
                    $this->$funcName();                 
                }
                public function add(){
                    $this->result = $this->numOne + $this->numTwo;
                }
                public function subtruct(){
                    $this->result = $this->numOne - $this->numTwo;   
                }
                public function multiple(){
                    $this->result = $this->numOne * $this->numTwo;   
                }
                public function divide(){
                    $this->result = $this->numOne / $this->numTwo;   
                }

                public function result(){
                    return $this->result;   
                }
         }



     $numOne=3; $numTwo=2; $funcName='multiple';
     $resultsOne = new NumberCalculation($numOne,$numTwo,$funcName);
     echo $resultsOne->result();
```